# Why am I being blocked from installing Visual Studio 2013 Express?

Tags: visual-studio

I am trying to install Visual Studio 2013 Express on Windows 7 Professional, and I am stuck here with the Web Platform Installer 5.0:

```
We're sorry. The following products have failed to install.
Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web (Default Locale)
This product did not install successfully: The installation is blocked.
Web Platform Installer 5.0 Log
```

I am not sure where to start.  I have other things installed for development which perhaps could be related, but I am very new when it comes to this stuff. I have XAMPP installed, and some other stuff related to development that is non-Microsoft.  I have SQL Server 2012 Enterprise (full version) installed, but I have set those to manual startup because they blocked my being able to start the Apache Web Server.  Any help or direction is much appreciated for what I could take a look at!

Here is what (I think) is the relevant portion of the log:

```
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Content-Encoding header: 'gzip'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Number of bytes downloaded over the internet: '22956'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Number of bytes after possible decompression: '76026'
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Error getting last-modified header, error code: 12150
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : HttpQueryInfoWithRetry for HTTP_QUERY_LAST_MODIFIED failed.
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Ratings file loaded successfully
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding product 'VWDOrVs2013AzurePack'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding dependency product 'WindowsAzureVSTools_2_3
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding dependency product 'VWD2013_Only
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding dependency product 'VWD2013_Only_BaseLocale
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Setting current install to 1
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting install sequence
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Downloading file 'http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=320700&clcid=409' to: C:\Users\jfinzel\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp5FB5.tmp
DownloadManager Information: 0 : http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=320700&clcid=409 responded with 302
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Expires: Sun, 20 Jul 2014 21:58:35 GMT
Location: http://download.microsoft.com/download/B/B/2/BB2AB17F-7BF1-477B-8BD5-488C843F122B/vns_full.exe
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sun, 20 Jul 2014 21:59:35 GMT
Content-Length: 211

DownloadManager Information: 0 : Content-disposition header: attachment
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Number of bytes downloaded over the internet: '1017600'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Number of bytes after possible decompression: '1017600'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : File 'C:\Users\jfinzel\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\VWD2013_Only_BaseLocale\5433BBE180ACD5278FC35E4829D7E01A96C11E01\vns_full.exe' already exists, deleting old copy of the file
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Moving downloaded file 'C:\Users\jfinzel\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp5FB5.tmp' to: C:\Users\jfinzel\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\VWD2013_Only_BaseLocale\5433BBE180ACD5278FC35E4829D7E01A96C11E01\vns_full.exe
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting EXE command for product 'Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web (Default Locale)'. Commandline is: 'C:\Users\jfinzel\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\VWD2013_Only_BaseLocale\5433BBE180ACD5278FC35E4829D7E01A96C11E01\vns_full.exe /q /norestart /ChainingPackage "WebPI" /CEIPConsent'. Process Id: 3148
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install exit code for product 'Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web (Default Locale)' is '-2147205120'
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Command failed. Retries left: 3
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting EXE command for product 'Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web (Default Locale)'. Commandline is: 'C:\Users\jfinzel\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\VWD2013_Only_BaseLocale\5433BBE180ACD5278FC35E4829D7E01A96C11E01\vns_full.exe /q /norestart /ChainingPackage "WebPI" /CEIPConsent'. Process Id: 4184
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install exit code for product 'Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web (Default Locale)' is '-2147205120'
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Command failed. Retries left: 2
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting EXE command for product 'Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web (Default Locale)'. Commandline is: 'C:\Users\jfinzel\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\VWD2013_Only_BaseLocale\5433BBE180ACD5278FC35E4829D7E01A96C11E01\vns_full.exe /q /norestart /ChainingPackage "WebPI" /CEIPConsent'. Process Id: 6012
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install exit code for product 'Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web (Default Locale)' is '-2147205120'
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Command failed. Retries left: 1
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting EXE command for product 'Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web (Default Locale)'. Commandline is: 'C:\Users\jfinzel\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\VWD2013_Only_BaseLocale\5433BBE180ACD5278FC35E4829D7E01A96C11E01\vns_full.exe /q /norestart /ChainingPackage "WebPI" /CEIPConsent'. Process Id: 508
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install exit code for product 'Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web (Default Locale)' is '-2147205120'
DownloadManager Error: 0 : Install return code for product 'Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web (Default Locale)' is Failure (The installation is blocked.)
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web (Default Locale) done install completed
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Increasing current install to 2
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting EXE command for product 'Windows Azure VS Tools - 2.3'. Commandline is: 'C:\Windows\sysnative\cmd.exe /C echo noop'. Process Id: 5824
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install exit code for product 'Windows Azure VS Tools - 2.3' is '0'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install return code for product 'Windows Azure VS Tools - 2.3' is Success
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product Windows Azure VS Tools - 2.3 done install completed
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Increasing current install to 3
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Dependency failed for product 'Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web Only'. Skipping install
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Dependency failed for product 'Windows Azure SDK for .NET (VS 2013) - 2.3'. Skipping install
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web Only had a dependency fail. Increasing install product to 4
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product Windows Azure SDK for .NET (VS 2013) - 2.3 had a dependency fail. Increasing install product to 5
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product: VWD2013_Only_BaseLocale, Install Status: InstallCompleted-Failure, Install Time: 00:00:39.8736700
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product: WindowsAzureVSTools_2_3, Install Status: InstallCompleted-Success, Install Time: 00:00:00.0624001
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product: VWD2013_Only, Install Status: DependencyFailed-None, Install Time: 00:00:00
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product: VWDOrVs2013AzurePack, Install Status: DependencyFailed-None, Install Time: 00:00:00
```

Comment: This might be more of a SuperUser question.

Comment: Contact your system administrator. If this is a personally managed machine, you may be able to get help on [su].

Comment: I'm sorry, but can't anyone try to help?  I posted on Stack Overflow, and they sent me here!?  Why am I being sent in circles?  I asked my question as clearly and thoroughly as possible and it relates to programming, and to server management.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than beat yourself up trying to troubleshoot the sometimes tempermental web platform installer, you can always just install directly from the Microsoft provided ISO instead: [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40787).  Also, you might check that you're on Windows 7 SP1, as that's listed as the minimum requirement for this version, NOT standard Windows 7.

Comment: I am on Windows 7 SP1.  I will see if I have any more luck with the ISO.  Thanks.

Comment: This isn't really taking care of my issue.  I was trying to install from http://www.asp.net/mvc, to get going with the MVC frameworks for C#.  When I install from the link you gave me, there are no web C# options for me at all.  And I think this may be related to the problems I am having installing from the asp.net/mvc link.

Comment: Good advice.  I will not spend days troubleshooting nor playing in the registry.